# Ionic: A bit Strange CORS issue with the IOS emulator

Tags: ios, django, ionic-framework, django-cors-headers

This is the code.

```
$http({ method: 'GET', url: imageUrl });
```

I'm using the `Ionic` framework. It works fine in web, andorid mobile and android emulator.

But when I use the same in the IOS 9.3 emulator(4.1.1), I get the error `XMLHttpRequest cannot load 'imageUrl'. Origin 'XXX' is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

I suppose I can eliminate any possible errors in the backend, as it is working with the other UI frameworks. Also in the backend(`Django framework`) I've set `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL` and `CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS` to `True`, added the IP address with port to `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST` and the needed headers(including `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`) in `CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS`.

So, Is there anything specific that needs to be done to make this error go away for the IOS emulator / platform ?

Answer (score 0):

When you run:

```
ionic cordova emulate ios -l -c -s
```

Which my guess is, is what you're doing, the emulator is started and is binding to your Mac's IP address instead of 'localhost'. This causes your receiving endpoint to see your Mac's IP in the request header of your get request and because this is a different address than the simulator has it will view your request as a Cross Domain Request.

Please try the following guide from the Ionic team:

[Handling CORS issues in Ionic](http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic)

**In short:**

1. Set a proxy in your ionic.config.json file:

   `{
     "name": "proxy-example",
     "app_id": "",
     "proxies": [
       {
         "path": "/api",
         "proxyUrl": "http://cors.api.com/api"
       }
     ]
   }`

   2. Point your request to localhost with the port that your live reloading server is using. You can set this in your emulate command like this:

   ionic cordova emulate ios -l -c -s --port 8080

Answer (score 0):

CORS issue is something that should be handled at the server. If you are using Azure to deploy your Web Api And Azure Database service then,
1. Open Dashboard.
2. Open your Web API app service.
3. Select CORS which is under API header from menu.
4. Make allow origins to * 
[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTpgp.png)
And also don't forget to allow all IP's[0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255] in the firewall setting in your Azure SQL server
[Reference Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3cq7.png)